# How to write avro output in hadoop map reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, avro, word-count

I wrote one Hadoop word count program which takes `TextInputFormat` input and is supposed to output word count in avro format.

Map-Reduce job is running fine but output of this job is readable using unix commands such as `more` or `vi`. I was expecting this output be unreadable as avro output is in binary format.

I have used mapper only, reducer is not present. I just want to experiment with avro so I am not worried about memory or stack overflow. Following the the code of mapper

```
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, AvroKey<String>, AvroValue<Integer>> {

    private Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] keys = value.toString().split("[\\s-*,\":]");
        for (String currentKey : keys) {
            int currentCount = 1;
            String currentToken = currentKey.trim().toLowerCase();
            if(wordCountMap.containsKey(currentToken)) {
                currentCount = wordCountMap.get(currentToken);
                currentCount++;
            }
            wordCountMap.put(currentToken, currentCount);
        }
        System.out.println("DEBUG : total number of unique words = " + wordCountMap.size());
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> currentKeyValue : wordCountMap.entrySet()) {
            AvroKey<String> currentKey = new AvroKey<String>(currentKeyValue.getKey());
            AvroValue<Integer> currentValue = new AvroValue<Integer>(currentKeyValue.getValue());
            context.write(currentKey, currentValue);
        }
    }
}
```

and driver code is as follows :

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Job avroJob = new Job(getConf());
    avroJob.setJarByClass(AvroWordCount.class);
    avroJob.setJobName("Avro word count");

    avroJob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    avroJob.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);

    AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(avroJob, Schema.create(Type.INT));
    AvroJob.setInputValueSchema(avroJob, Schema.create(Type.STRING));

    AvroJob.setMapOutputKeySchema(avroJob, Schema.create(Type.STRING));
    AvroJob.setMapOutputValueSchema(avroJob, Schema.create(Type.INT));

    AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(avroJob, Schema.create(Type.STRING));
    AvroJob.setOutputValueSchema(avroJob, Schema.create(Type.INT));


    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(avroJob, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(avroJob, new Path(args[1]));

    return avroJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

I would like to know how do avro output looks like and what am I doing wrong in this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest release of Avro library includes an updated [example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/avro/trunk/doc/examples/mr-example/src/main/java/example/MapReduceAvroWordCount.java) of their ColorCount example adopted for MRv2. I suggest you to look at it, use the same pattern as they use in Reduce class or just [extend AvroMapper](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/mr.html#Example%3a+ColorCount). Please note that using [Pair](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/Pair.html) class instead of AvroKey+AvroValue is also essential for running Avro on Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to example. My problem is solved but I have one more problem. If I am using avro file created by some other program as an input to mapper then how do avro distributes schema of that file to all the mappers? As per my understanding if avro schema is written at the start of avro file, this schema won't be available to all the mappers except first mapper.

Comment: Here is what [Avro Specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Object+Container+Files) says: A file has a schema, and all objects stored in the file must be written according to that schema, using binary encoding. Objects are stored in blocks that may be compressed. Synchronization markers are used between blocks to permit efficient splitting of files for MapReduce processing.

My understanding is that schema is stored once per file, but during the split process we write the schema into each part and markers help us to do it efficiently.

Comment: Now I am facing the same problem with Avro1.7.4 version. Can you tell what did you do to solve this problem ?