# How to output a sequence file in mapreduce program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I have a map-reduce job which takes an avro file as input, so the mapper extends the `AvroMapper` class. Here is the driver program

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Job configuration
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(SeqFileGenerator.class);
    conf.setJobName("Sequence File Generator");

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("in"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("out"));

    AvroJob.setMapperClass(conf, AvroReaderMapper.class);

    AvroJob.setInputSchema(conf, ContentPackage.SCHEMA$);       
    AvroJob.setOutputSchema(conf, Pair.getPairSchema(Schema.create(Type.STRING),Schema.create(Type.INT)));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);

}
```

As shown in the code, I have to use the `AvroJob` class to define my job. I'd like my program to output a sequence file but it looks like that I have to define a schema for the output otherwise it doesn't run. In other words, the output has to be avro!! How can I output a sequence file in this program?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876062/how-to-write-avro-output-in-hadoop-map-reduce

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help because the answers suggest extending the mapper class from the AvroMapper which I'm already done and the problem is the AvroMapper looks to accept Avro input and output only Avro too. But I need to output sequence file, anstead of avro.